# Destroy jQuery script when class is added to body

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently working on a website with a dynamic layout. Whenever the window resizes it  checks (trough jQuery) which layout is most suiting (I've setup a few pixel ranges for that) and applies either a .high .med or .low class to the elements on the page.

Thus far I've got pretty much everything worked out. There are just a few things left I can't figure out.

Because the layout is heavily relying on floats I've used a "equalheights" jQuery plugin to get the columns to size to an equal height:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.equalHeights = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
        tallest = (minHeight) ? minHeight : 0;
        this.each(function() {

            if($(this).height() > tallest) {
                tallest = $(this).height();
            }
        });

        if((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).height(tallest).css;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is when the layout switches the columns will keep being resized. This usually wouldn't be an issue, but the layouts differ quite a bit.

First of I tried to add an if "has class" statement before the resizing happens and this didn't work because the script didn't "see" the class when it was added. This might have to do with the order of execution of the functions.

I should note that I'm just a beginner (4 weeks of javascript/jQuery experience), but I'm very willing to learn more.

Comment: Well... if you don't want this function to be called on resize... don't do it.

Comment: I'm only calling it here (in a separate script.js file): 
`else if (med < windowWidth){
     $('body').removeClass('med');
     $('body').removeClass('low');
     $('body').addClass('high');   
     $("#wrapper, #nav-bar, #menu-wrapper").equalHeights();
     $("#main-wrap, #left-gradient, #main-inner-gradient-right").equalHeights();
    }`
am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I would **Suggest you to use CSS3 Media** Queries rather than Script for the **Responsive/ Adaptive Web page design.**

Please have a look at [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)

These **do not process a lot**, hence **Light weight and most modern browsers and Devices support CSS3** hence a **convenient and reliable Option.**

Comment: Thank you very much! I've designed a few html5 sites already, but compatibility with older browsers was holding me back to use it here. The solution offered should solve this.

Comment: Besides if you target **old browsers** and need to show rounded corners or other **css3 properties not supported by old browsers** you may have a look at the **CSS3 PIE** on the link: **http://css3pie.com/**